# How to pass a var from py to kv with click button?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Hy. I have a little code that: has a button on top of the screen, and a circle at the middle. When you click the color should change to the trafic light color, but it doesnt do it. Does can someone help me? Thank you!

**image_test.py**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

light = 0

class myScreen(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.img_src = 'images/traffic_light_red.png'

    def change_color(self):
        global light
        img = [
            'images/traffic_light_red.png',
            'images/traffic_light_yellow.png',
            'images/traffic_light_green.png'
            ]
        light += 1 
        if light > 2: light = 0
        self.img_src = img[light]
        print(light, self.img_src)

class myImageApp(App):
    def build(self): return myScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myImageApp().run()
```

**myImage.kv**

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
#:import AsyncImage kivy.uix.image.AsyncImage

<myScreen>:

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1.,1.,0.8,1.)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Button:
        text: 'traffic light color'
        size_hint: [None, None]
        size: 200, 100
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'top':1}
        on_press: root.change_color()
    
    AsyncImage:
        source: 'images/traffic_light_red.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy wy is to add an `id` to the `AsyncImage`, like this:

```
AsyncImage:
    id: img
    source: 'images/traffic_light_red.png'
```

And use that in your `change_color()` method:

```
def change_color(self):
    global light
    img = [
        'images/traffic_light_red.png',
        'images/traffic_light_yellow.png',
        'images/traffic_light_green.png'
        ]
    light += 1 
    if light > 2: light = 0
    self.ids.img.source = img[light]  # use `ids` to access the image
    print(light, self.img_src)
```